# How to plot this data in matlab?

Tags: matlab

how can i plots in matlab this data
e field in (x,y,z)

### Time / us                E-field (X; -10 -10 -1) [pw]/real

```
                   0                  1.3767911e-006
      2.8537992e-006                  1.6630072e-006
      5.7075984e-006                  1.1496669e-006
      8.5613976e-006                  1.3562865e-006
      1.1415197e-005                   1.936412e-006
      1.4268996e-005                  1.6920654e-006
      1.7122795e-005                  1.2527399e-006
      1.9976594e-005                  1.5579486e-006
      2.2830393e-005                  2.0703696e-006
      2.5684193e-005                  2.4029719e-006
```

### Time / us                E-field (X; -10 -12 -1) [pw]/real

```
                   0                  1.3767911e-006
      2.8537992e-006                  1.6630072e-006
      5.7075984e-006                  1.1496669e-006
      8.5613976e-006                  1.3562865e-006
      1.1415197e-005                   1.936412e-006
      1.4268996e-005                  1.6920654e-006
      1.7122795e-005                  1.2527399e-006
      1.9976594e-005                  1.5579486e-006
      2.2830393e-005                  2.0703696e-006
      2.5684193e-005                  2.4029719e-006
```

### Time / us                E-field (X; -10 -14 -1) [pw]/real

```
                   0                  1.3767911e-006
      2.8537992e-006                  1.6630072e-006
      5.7075984e-006                  1.1496669e-006
      8.5613976e-006                  1.3562865e-006
      1.1415197e-005                   1.936412e-006
      1.4268996e-005                  1.6920654e-006
      1.7122795e-005                  1.2527399e-006
      1.9976594e-005                  1.5579486e-006
      2.2830393e-005                  2.0703696e-006
      2.5684193e-005                  2.4029719e-006
```

### Time / us                E-field (X; -10 -16 -1) [pw]/real

```
                   0                  1.3767911e-006
      2.8537992e-006                  1.6630072e-006
      5.7075984e-006                  1.1496669e-006
      8.5613976e-006                  1.3562865e-006
      1.1415197e-005                   1.936412e-006
      1.4268996e-005                  1.6920654e-006
      1.7122795e-005                  1.2527399e-006
      1.9976594e-005                  1.5579486e-006
      2.2830393e-005                  2.0703696e-006
      2.5684193e-005                  2.4029719e-006
```

.
.
.

thank you

Comment: Please read the manual, it is a very trivial question

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [
               0                  1.3767911e-006
  2.8537992e-006                  1.6630072e-006
  5.7075984e-006                  1.1496669e-006
  8.5613976e-006                  1.3562865e-006
  1.1415197e-005                   1.936412e-006
  1.4268996e-005                  1.6920654e-006
  1.7122795e-005                  1.2527399e-006
  1.9976594e-005                  1.5579486e-006
  2.2830393e-005                  2.0703696e-006
  2.5684193e-005                  2.4029719e-006 ];
plot(A(:,1),A(:,2))
```

for more, see [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f3-27853.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you're trying to plot the electric field strength at a point in space.  This is what I would try:

```
    aa = [ 0                  1.3767911e-006
  2.8537992e-006                  1.6630072e-006
  5.7075984e-006                  1.1496669e-006
  8.5613976e-006                  1.3562865e-006
  1.1415197e-005                   1.936412e-006
  1.4268996e-005                  1.6920654e-006
  1.7122795e-005                  1.2527399e-006
  1.9976594e-005                  1.5579486e-006
  2.2830393e-005                  2.0703696e-006
  2.5684193e-005                  2.4029719e-006];

  plot( aa(:,1)*1e6, aa(:,2)*1e6 )
  ylabel('E Field in \mu V/m');
  xlabel('Time in \mu s')
```

[image: Plot]

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @Alireza Akbari Um, sure that would be fine.  Did I answer your question(if so please mark it up :-) )?  Are you looking for like a 3D movie plot?

Comment: thank you for your answer, i want plot these data in 2D and 3D dimensional,but theses data are variations e-field with time in (x,y,z).

Comment: ok, your efield data is the same for every point and varies only with time and not location.

Comment: thank you,yes, my data are in 10 line (x,y,z); and my e-field data varies only with time on a line.when my sensor goes to a new location again my data varies with time on that place,now i want plot these data on a plate with them.

Comment: @Alireza Akbari, you can send me the data if you want, however, i'm not sure how you want this data to look.  Also, please accept my answer.